# Нужен regex для проверки имени файла

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

`вид строки - "имя.расширение"`

- Имя не больше 8 символов
- расширение не больше 3
- сама строка не больше 20 символов

почему файл a.in.txt выдает как подходящий при таком шаблоне:
`^(([A-Za-z]){1,9}\.([A-Za-z]){1,4}){,21}$`

Comment: вид это не часть строки, это как должна выглядеть строка

Comment: вы разрешили 21 раз написать a.ina.ina.in

Comment: Используйте `^[A-Za-z]{1,8}\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}$`. Откуда у вас условие "не больше 20 символов", если всего 8 + 1 + 3 = 12?

Comment: спасибо, ваше регу подходит. я видимо слишком усложнил все. вопрос про условие не совсем понял, строка же не одна, просто попалась та, где меньше 20

Comment: я в душе не чаю, что за слово "регу".

Comment: @strawdog, для меня "регу" гораздо понятнее чем "я в душе не чаю". Когда я первый раз услышал от нового знакомого фразу "я в душе не чаю" - был сильно озадачен и не понял о чем он. Пришлось даже [загуглить](https://yandex.ru/q/question/sushchestvuet_li_vyrazhenie_v_dushe_ne_ot_669fc8e6/) :-D

Comment: Вот пример если из строки которая не длиннее 22 символов нужно выбирать файл с условиями: https://regex101.com/r/lO6DpP/3, 22 символа регулируются вначале, частично переработанный regex от Wiktor Stribizew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `^([A-Za-z]{1,9}\.[A-Za-z]{1,4}){,21}$` (лишние подмаски удалены) находит совпадение в строках, которые целиком состоят из 0-21 повторов 1-9 букв, точки и 1-4 букв. См. [пример работы своего выражения](https://regex101.com/r/lO6DpP/2).

Используйте

```cs
^[A-Za-z]{1,8}\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/lO6DpP/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[A-Za-z]{1,8}` - от одной до восьми букв ASCII
- `\.` - символ точки
- `[A-Za-z]{1,3}` - от одной до трёх букв ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.

[Пример на Python](https://ideone.com/sz3ecU):

```py
import re
filenames = ['in.txt','abcdEFGHI.htm']
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename, bool(re.search(r'^[A-Za-z]{1,8}\.[A-Za-z]{1,3}$', filename)), sep = ' => ')
```

Результат:

```py
in.txt => True
abcdEFGHI.htm => False
```